# Swiper JS пролистывает не до конца

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

Недавно начал изучать вёрстку, но столкнулся с такой проблемой:
На десктопной версии всё работает отлично, а вот при ширине <992px, где отображается один слайд, слайдер листается криво.
[image]

HTML

```
<section id="objects" class="objects">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="objects-content">
      <h2 class="title title-center">Примеры наших объектов</h2>
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img class="slide__image" src="/img/objects/1.jpg" alt="image" />
          <h4 class="slide__name">Название объекта</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img class="slide__image" src="/img/objects/2.jpg" alt="image" />
          <h4 class="slide__name">Название объекта</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img class="slide__image" src="/img/objects/3.jpg" alt="image" />
          <h4 class="slide__name">Название объекта</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section
```

CSS

```
.objects {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 220px;
    &-content {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }
}



.swiper {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 350px;

    &-wrapper {
        height: 410px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    &-slide {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
}

.slide {
    &__image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit:cover;
    }
    &__name {
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #073F6D;
    }
}

.title {
    &-center {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

JS

```
new Swiper('.objects-content', {
    grabCursor: true,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView: 3,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 3000,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
    }
});

window.addEventListener('resize', move);

function move(){
    const viewport_width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
    if (viewport_width <= 992) {
        new Swiper('.objects-content', {
            slidesPerView: 1,
        });
    }
}

move();
```

Буду максимально благодарен за помощь :)

Comment: кто Вас этому научил? window.addEventListener('resize', move);

Comment: Взял с просторов интернета

Comment: Не все что плохо лежит стоит брать)) Обратите внимание на вторую часть моего ответа (обновление), там именно тот вариант который Вам нужен, можете плюсануть мой ответ в качестве максимальной благодарности:)

Comment: Ого :) Невероятно) Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Пожалуйста, не забудьте нажать треугольник `вверх` напротив моего ответа)

Comment: Да я бы тысячу раз нажал, но... "Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я предполагаю, что ошибочное поведение которое Вы наблюдаете связано с утечкой памяти и созданием нескольких экземпляров одновременно, да еще и с разными опциями.

В вашем случае `swiper` создается бесконтрольно — т.е. нет ни его уничтожения, ни контроля за количеством экземпляров, что порождает утечку памяти, привожу скрин в качестве доказательства где память вырасла с `2.63mb` до `7.48mb`:

[image: утечка памяти]

Дело в том что библиотека `SwiperJS` не предполагает что компонент cлайдер будет пересоздаваться (у них в документации он объявляется через `const` т.е. константой), хотя в [API](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#methods-and-properties) библиотеки присутствует метод для уничтожения `экземпляра слайдера` как раз для Вашего случая:

> swiper.destroy(deleteInstance, cleanStyles)
>
> уничтожает экземпляр slider и отписывается от всех слушателей событий

Применение этого метода перед созданием нового экземпляра позволяет избежать утечки памяти, что видно на следующем скрине память возвращается к `2.51mb`:

[image: память восстанавливается]

Сам код, если его не сильно рефакторить и оставить приблизительно в том же виде будет выглядеть так:

```
let perView = 3 // текущее количество слайдов на странице

function createSwiper(slidesPerView){
  return new Swiper('.objects-content', {
    grabCursor: true,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 3000,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
    }
  });
}

let swiper = createSwiper(perView)

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
function resize(){
    const viewport_width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);

    if (viewport_width <= 992 && perView === 3) {
      perView = 1  // было 3 делаем 1 — нужен экземпляр
      swiper.destroy(); // уничтожаем предыдущий экземпляр
      swiper = createSwiper(perView) // создаем новый
    } else if ( viewport_width > 992 && perView === 1) {
      perView = 3  // было 1 делаем 3 — нужен экземпляр
      swiper.destroy(); // уничтожаем предыдущий экземпляр
      swiper = createSwiper(perView) // создаем новый
    }
}
resize();
```

Тут я завел отдельную переменную `perView`, для того чтобы создавать экземпляр только в том случае когда он будет отличаться от текущего параметром отображаемых слайдов, если количество слайдов будет совпадать — нет смысла создавать новый экземпляр.

Вообще, для события `resize` лучше использовать `debounce` функцию которая позволяет обрабатывать его с некоторой задержкой а соответственно снизить нагрузку на браузер вычисления новых состояний. Подробнее можете почитать [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/task/debounce)

**Решение основанное на [брекпоинтах](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#parameters)**:

> breakpoints   object
>
> Позволяет установить разные параметры для разных контрольных точек
> (размеров экрана). В точках останова можно изменить не все параметры,
> а только те, которые не требуют другой верстки и логики, например
> slidesPerView, slidesPerGroup, spaceBetween, grid.rows. Такие
> параметры, как loop и effect, работать не будут — требуют пересоздания слайдера.

```
function createSwiper(selector, slidesPerViewMin, slidesPerViewMax){
  return new Swiper(selector, {
    grabCursor: true,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView: slidesPerViewMin,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 3000,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    breakpoints: {
      992: {
        slidesPerView: slidesPerViewMax
      }
    }
  });
}

const swiper = createSwiper('.objects-content', 1, 3)
```

[Пример](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/master/demos/380-responsive-breakpoints.html) в исходниках гитхаба